# Lighttable -simplest working groovy file - exception

Tags: groovy, lighttable

I installed Light table in 0.7.2 for linux x64(Ubuntu 14.04).
I installed plugin Groovy 0.0.7

I stored in file test.groovy

```
println (1..10)
```

When I try to evaluate it(ctrl+enter) i got

```
We couldn't connect. Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's what we got: 

null
null
find: `/usr/bin/../embeddable': No such file or directory
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at      java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

I am new to Lighttable, how could I fix it ?

Comment: Have you got GROOVY_HOME set? Looks like it thinks groovy is in the `/usr` directory

Comment: Setting GROOVY_HOME not solved a problem. I currently read about connectors to groovy, still it is not clearly described.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the plugin and check where it is being installed would be the quickest route. The other alternative is to embed the plugin into the project which would take you a bit of extra time.

Here would be the two quickest suggestions:

1. Pull the plugin out. Then do `git clean -fdx` and be sure the plugin is gone. Then reinstall from scratch.
2. Find where the plugin is located. By default, `clojure` and `groovy` typically are located at *LightTable/deploy/plugins*. If it is, then this is easy, do a `git pull` on the directory because the .jar may not be in the same location as the plugin itself.

Try number 1 first. It is simpler and faster to accomplish.